# Certificate location for azure web apps

Tags: certificate-store

I have an MVC web app that can locate a certificate when running on my local machine.  Everything works fine.

Trying to deploy in on Azure is where the problem occurs.

I have a webapp on azure, i publish, everything not requiring the cert works fine.

in my code, I have the CertificateStore = "My"
and the CeritifaceteStoreLocation = "LocalMachine"

I am sure this is the problem, but I do not know the solution.

On the Azure portal, under the Webapp config section, the certificate is there.

(I am trying to find it by thumbprint)

Any thoughts?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the StoreLocation to CurrentUser.